# Linq to sql, query many-to-many with count of other

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a many-to-many relation and I'm trying to create the query which will fetch me the left side and a property which counts the number of records which are refferecend by it.

following is my query

```
    var dbSet = await (from user in _dbContext.Users
                       where (from courseUsers in _dbContext.CourseUsers select courseUsers.UserId).Contains(user.Id)
                        select new
                        {
                           Name = user.Name,
                           Id = user.Id,
                           CourseUsersCount = _dbContext.CourseUsers.Where(item => item.UserId == user.Id).Count()
                        })
                        .ToListAsync();
```

What I don't like is how CourseUsersCount is computed. I would also like to include the total count property and the way I would do it is to add another property on the `select` which would just do a count over the `_dbContext.CourseUsers`  and after that do another in-memory transformation.

I the end I would like a result with this structure to be created

```
{
   count: 1000,
   data: [{
      Id: 1,
      Name: "c",
      CourseUsersCount: 2
   }]
}
```

and I want to know how can I do this directly using linq-to-sql.

Comment: You're looking for a JOIN and a GROUPBY

Comment: Please read tag summaries before adding them to your question.

Comment: That said, I don't understand why you don't use the navigation properties you showed in your previous question.

Comment: Performance, I've noticed that odata queries are 3 to 4 times slower

Comment: OData can't determine how you should collect data using EF. It's not clear what you mean. It looks like you're merely trying to work around the issue in your previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you have to use GroupBy for such calculation:

```cs
var query
    from user in _dbContext.Users
    from courseUsers in user.Courses
    group user by new { user.Id, user.Name } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.Id,
        g.Key.Name,
        CourseUsersCount = g.Count()
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a Group By to merge all the CourseUsers into a single set, followed by a Join to attach the Users to it.

```
from course in _dbContext.CourseUsers // outer sequence
group course by course.UserId into courseGrp
join user in _dbContext.Users //inner sequence 
on courseGrp.Key equals user.UserId// key selector 
select new { // result selector 
  CourseUsersCount = courseGrp.Count(),
  user.Name,
  user.Id
};
```